# How to use attributes in the new Console Template in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to write an application which will be able to take a flag as an argument to allow the user to decide if they would like to run the application with or without a GUI. The solution which I am trying to implement is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930258/13441670), however, in the [new Console template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) in  C# you no longer have access to the

`static void Main(string[] args)` line, and so I am unsure where to place the `[STAThread]` attribute as the user suggested.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "you no longer have access to the `static void Main(string[] args)` line."  Surely the program still has an entry point.

Comment: It does, but if you check out the second link, they've removed access to that line I believe in the newer version of C#.

Comment: Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the MS document didn't seem to help much as I want to target .NET 6. The workaround which seems to work is

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("In the Main function");
}

Main(args);
```

Comment: The document states "Switch to .NET 5, create your project, and then switch back to .NET 6."